# How to share contact with telegram bot to reply message on IOS?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am writng telegram bot on nodejs with [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api). For authorization i use reply keyboard with request_contact param. [request_contact keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgLUG.png). When the user clicks on button "Поделиться контактом" (Share contact), on desktop version, web version and android, the user sends their contact with reply on previous message. On previous message i bind replyHandler(for reply contact) and authorize the user.

On ios if we click on "Share contact" button, the user send their contact without replying. Therefore i can't handle this contact and auth user.

Maybe someone knows what's problem?
Or how to solve it in another way?
Maybe it's native telegram api restriction or bug?

[sharing contact on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8QAX.png)
[sharing contact on ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbA5y.png)

I am trying to share contact with reply on message. On Android all works fine.
On ios contact sends without replying.